# Is doing facial exercises to obtain dimples considered changing the creation of Allah?

Tags: halal-haram, human-body

Assalamualaikum everyone!

I’ve been doing some facial exercises lately: I don’t naturally have dimples but because of those exercises I’m getting dimples.

Is this considered changing the creation of Allah?

Comment: Welcome to islam community. 
Changing the creation of Allah involved only Surgical procedures (by cutting eskin or doing operation on limbs or any body part) otherwise exercise is fine.

Comment: May Allah Reward You For This

Answer (score 0):

Walikumsalam, Exercising is not changing the creation of Allah, he has given you ability to exercise there is nothing wrong with it, unless you give all your focus to your appearance and forget about what's really important in your life !

Allah knows the best !

Answer (score -2):

Whatever **direct** or **indirect** way you do to get to the same end/result which is changing the original creation of Allah of your figure (face and body) is **Haram** if it is for increasing your beauty and/or improving your looks, not *for example* treating an illness or fixing a deformation.

The facial exercises are **Haram** if they change your original face appearance for that purpose. You don't have (natural) dimples; thus, it is considered a change to your cheeks which have basically no holes.

Those are **explicitly** stated in Qur'an as Satan orders to the servants of Allah (Muslims), and one of his orders is "Changing the creation of Allah" which is also stated in Qur'an **explicitly**.

In Surah Al-Nisa (4):

[Verse 117](https://quran.com/4/117):

In Arabic (the original text):

> وَإِنْ يَدْعُونَ إِلَّا شَيْطَانًا مَرِيدًا

Its translation:

> They call upon instead of Him none but female [deities], and they [actually] call upon none but a rebellious Satan.

[Verse 118](https://quran.com/4/118):

In Arabic (the original text):

> لَعَنَهُ اللَّهُ وَقَالَ لَأَتَّخِذَنَّ مِنْ عِبَادِكَ نَصِيبًا مَفْرُوضًا

Its translation:

> Whom Allah has cursed. For he had said, "I will surely take from among Your servants a specific portion.

[Verse 119](https://quran.com/4/119):

In Arabic (the original text):

> وَلَأُضِلَّنَّهُمْ وَلَأُمَنِّيَنَّهُمْ وَلَآمُرَنَّهُمْ فَلَيُبَتِّكُنَّ آذَانَ الْأَنْعَامِ وَلَآمُرَنَّهُمْ فَلَيُغَيِّرُنَّ خَلْقَ اللَّهِ وَمَنْ يَتَّخِذِ الشَّيْطَانَ وَلِيًّا مِنْ دُونِ اللَّهِ فَقَدْ خَسِرَ خُسْرَانًا مُبِينًا

Its translation:

> And I will mislead them, and I will arouse in them [sinful] desires, and I will command them so they will slit the ears of cattle, and I will command them so they will change the creation of Allah ." And whoever takes Satan as an ally instead of Allah has certainly sustained a clear loss.

---

[Source_1](https://mawdoo3.com/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85_%D8%B9%D9%85%D9%84%D9%8A%D8%A9_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%BA%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%AA)

[Source_2](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/129370/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%B7-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%AA%D8%BA%D9%8A%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%82-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87)

Comment: So.. is simply growing up haram? Because isn't it changing the original creation of Allah?

Comment: @user2007 - Growing up is normal procedure humans go through due to Allah's creation (i.e., that's how He created us). It is not something caused by you or others

Comment: But you eat though. You keep your body healthy. So you grow up. And people do exercises to keep themselves fit. Which in return makes their body not get fat.